# Is there a batman in arrowverse?

Tags: dc, batman, arrowverse

In the Arrowverse, the  Multiverse of *The Flash*, *Supergirl*, etc, Supergirl  references her cousin "Superman". Does that mean Batman or other DC characters are also there?

Comment: Batman is everywhere ;)

Comment: If you’ll allow me to blow your mind, when Supergirl mentions her cousin Superman, it means that Superman exists in her universe.  It doesn’t mean anything else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Batman has been referenced in three of the universes

**Earth-1 (main universe)**

Bruce Wayne exists in this universe, is will known, and lives in Gotham. There is no confirmation of him engaging in vigilante activities.

> **Oliver Queen:** Photos can be doctored. They could have put Bruce Wayne's head on that body. Has Bruce Wayne left Gotham to hang out in Star City recently? No.
>
> <sub>Arrow season 6 episode 2, "Tribute"</sub>

Additionally, the future newspaper shown in the Flash mentioned a "Wayne Tech" company, which may possibly be associated with Bruce Wayne.

> [image]
>
> <sub>Flash season 1, episode 1, "Pilot"</sub>

*Edit (December 11, 2018)*: The fact that Bruce Wayne is Batman in Earth-1 has been confirmed during this year's crossover when Supergirl, Green Arrow and the Flash visit Gotham City. Precisely, he was Batman until he disappeared from Gotham City 3 years ago. His cousin is now replacing him as Batwoman, and will have her own spin-off show in 2019, so we may have more information later on. [Edit written by Taladris on ibid's suggestion]

**Earth-2 (Flash alternate universe)**

A character by the name of "Bruce" was found on Earth-2's Barry Allen's phone alongside "Hal" and "Diana". Nothing else was said about him. (Note that Earth-2 Barry doesn't have the speedforce.)

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://pmctvline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/the-flash-earth-two-barry-phone1.jpg))</sub>

> <sub>Flash season 2, episode 13, "Welcome to Earth-2"</sub>

**Earth-38 (Supergirl universe)**

An unnamed vigilante matching Batman's description was said to have once worked with Superman.

> **Kara:** My cousin worked with a vigilante once, tons of gadgets, lots of demons. Vigilantes are nuts!.
>
> <sub>Supergirl season 2, episode 7, "The Darkest Place"</sub>
>
> **James Olsen:** So, people see this big guy in this scary mask and they freak out, they run away.
>
> **Winn Schott:** Just like Clark's friend.
>
> **James Olsen:** Oh, you mean...
>
> **Winn Schott:** I feel like they're more frenemies
>
> <sub>Supergirl season 2, episode 20, "City of Lost Children"</sub>

Comment: Legends 1x01 had Rip say something like “I’ve seen men of steel die and dark knights fall”, suggesting that at some point in Earth-1’s timeline Batman was a thing (along with Superman).

Comment: @Thunderforge - More likely that he’d popped over to another universe.

Comment: @Adamant - Legends doesn't really do multiverse travel.

Comment: @ibid - Sure, I know, but Rip Hunter could easily have done so at some point.

Comment: +1 For including references. I just wanted to say "If its part of DC then batman exists" but this is much better

Comment: @JesseBarnett I started thinking of counterexamples (e.g. Watchmen, Static Shock, DC Super Hero Girls), then realized that Batman was somehow referenced in all of them. Guess that's pretty much true.

Comment: @ibit Barry did. he went from dc universe to marvel universe and back.

Comment: And what about the other Justice league members @ibit? Do you know anything about them? WW, RT, BB? Thanks for your answer tho. and refs.

Comment: @Sam - When has Barry visited the Marvel universe in *Legends of Tomorrow*?

Comment: @Sam - Wonder Woman, Green Lantern, and Blue Beetle have all been referenced a bunch of times. Not sure about the rest. If you want any specifics you should probably ask a separate question.

Comment: @ibid in the comics. He ran and vanished. then he got into marvel universe and thought his name was buried alien (b.a) like Barry Allen and he was much faster than the marvel speedsters

Comment: @Sam - I thought this question was about CW's arrowverse. Regardless, my comment to Adamant was specifically about the CW show *Legends of Tomorrow*. As far as in aware, no such scene happened on that show.

Comment: @ibid that's true. it is about cw, and this never happened in cw. but it did in dc. and cw is just an copy of dc with a few adjustments

Comment: @Sam - Unless I completely misunderstood it, the entire premise of your original question is that events in comics *cannot* be assumed to have happened in the CWverse without evidence that they happened. Anyways my comment to Adamant is that things in *Legends of Tomorrow* shouldn't be chalked up to multiverse travel because *that show* by principle doesn't do multiverse travel.

Comment: @ibid yes you are right

Comment: @ibid what about red tornado? Is he built? Did he want to become a hero instead of hero? Or isnt he built at all?

Comment: @Sam - You should probably post that as a new question.

Comment: The fact that Bruce is Batman in Earth-1 has been confirmed during this year's crossover when Supergirl, Green Arrow and the Flash visit Gotham City. Precisely, he was Batman until he disappeared from Gotham City 3 years ago.

Comment: @Taladris - I most probably will not judge a chance to catch up to the crossover in a while, so feel free to edit that information into this answer or post it as a separate answer.

Comment: To answer the Red Tornado question, he appeared in an early episode of the first season of Supergirl.